# Dockerfile automation

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there is a possibility in automating the Dockerfile. I'm trying to create the Dockerfile programmatically.

From UI I need to get the information and pass the values as an argument to create the Dockerfile. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Im new to docker,could you please guide me how to implement it?

Comment: First, you should know how to create docker files manually. Second, you should be able to program. Then combine these two abilities.

Comment: i wrote a dockerfile manually and i built it. But i dont have hands-on in programming. My Dockerfile is

FROM java:8 

# Install maven
RUN apt-get update  
RUN apt-get install -y maven

WORKDIR /code

# Prepare by downloading dependencies
ADD pom.xml /code/pom.xml  
RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]  
RUN ["mvn", "verify"]

# Adding source, compile and package into a fat jar
ADD src /code/src  
RUN ["mvn", "package"]

EXPOSE 4567  
CMD ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java", "-jar", "target/sparkexample-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]

Comment: @AleksandrKovalev is right.  I think, in general, to prepare and run a customized docker container, you'd have to have 3 things.  1) Prepare a Dockerfile.  2) Build it and 3) Run it.  For #1, depending on what your UI backend is, you would have to be able to manipulate the filesystem to inject variables into the flatfile Dockerfile in the local file system.  For #2, your UI must be able to `cd` to the folder where your Dockerfile is saved and pass `docker build` into the command line and execute the command.  For #3, it would also have to pass `docker run` into the command line and execute it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this approach is useful for you:

Example dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV APP ${APP}
RUN apt-get install ${APP}
```

Then you can run the following command:

```
$ docker build --build-arg APP=tmux .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> d55e68e6cc9c
Step 2 : ARG APP
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8331d5368631
Step 3 : ENV APP ${APP}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7bcd5ac4cbb7
Step 4 : RUN apt-get install -y ${APP}
 ---> Running in fa0ed50f6ab9
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libevent-2.0-5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libevent-2.0-5 tmux
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 373 kB of archives.
After this operation, 895 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libevent-2.0-5 amd64 2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1 [126 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main tmux amd64 1.8-5 [247 kB]
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
Fetched 373 kB in 2s (142 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-2.0-5:amd64.
(Reading database ... 11542 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libevent-2.0-5_2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tmux.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/tmux_1.8-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tmux (1.8-5) ...
Setting up libevent-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up tmux (1.8-5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
 ---> 36175c4fdd16
Removing intermediate container fa0ed50f6ab9
Successfully built 36175c4fdd16
```

In that particular case we are defining which package we want to install on building time.

This is working since version `1.9`. You can take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

Answer (score 1):

You can Use [Tiller](http://tiller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), 
A ruby gem that generates text file, configuration files (.yaml , .conf ..etc ). This can be used to generate Dockerfile on the fly. Explore Tiller its is awsome..!!

Example:

1. Install `tiller` gem :

   `$ gem install tiller`
2. Create The following dir structure

   [image]
3. Append the `common.yaml` :

   [image: contents of common.yaml]
4. Create the `dockerfile_template`:

   [image]
5. Run tiller command inside `dockerfile` dir:

   - for generating template for dev env (default)
     `$ tiller -b .`
   - for generating template for production env by passing `-e production` flag 
     `$ tiller -b . -e production`

   > tiller v1.2.0 (https://github.com/markround/tiller) 
   >   Template generation completed
6. Now you can see Dockerfile created in the current dir

   [image]

view its content when executed with both the environments

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Docker has plenty of documentation about how to write a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)! , but it can be a little overwhelming at the beginning, maybe yo can use one of the examples provided by resin.io as a [reference](https://github.com/resin-io/Hello-Java/blob/master/Dockerfile) to start.

```
# Base image
FROM resin/rpi-raspbian:wheezy

# Install Java 8
RUN echo 'deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list && \
echo oracle-java8-jdk shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install oracle-java8-jdk && \
apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy /app folder
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Compile Hello.java (main)
RUN javac /usr/src/app/Hello.java

# Run shell file with the command java -cp . Hello
CMD /usr/src/app/run.sh
```

Intellij has a plugin that helps you write your dockerfile, but I strongly recommend you to start doing it manually.

Comment: While the link you provided may answer the question, it is best to put the essential parts directly into your answer in case the page at the link expires in the future.